# Erro visual Studio não reconhece linguagem

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

Estou com um problema no Visual Studio Code. Instalei o *Node.JS*, depois o *VS Code* e logo em seguida o *code runner*. Porém, o *VS Code* não está reconhecendo os comandos.

Digito `console.log("texto")` e fala que a linguagem não é suportada.

Como corrigir?

Comment: Onde você digita esse comando?? 

Comment: Abro uma pasta e um new file e dígito.

Comment: Qual a extenção do arquivo? Já tentou salvar o arquivo como .JS e verifica se ele reconhece?