# Erro vsCode - Linguagem não reconhecida

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem ajudar?

Cod Runner e node instalados.

Comment: Possível duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/414201/99718

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro visual Studio não reconhece linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414201/erro-visual-studio-n%c3%a3o-reconhece-linguagem)